# Qt Creator 4.8.4. windows 7 - 64bit installation

Tags: qt, windows-7, installation

I have some difficulties with QT, which I need for school for some GUI applications.

I have recently done these steps:

1) `mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe`from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/) installed to C:\MinGW\ with default settings.

2) Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB) from [QT Project](http://qt-project.org/downloads) installed to C:\Qt\  with default settings. Here an error occurs:

```
    !!!There is a problem with your MinQW instalation
    !!!g++ not found in c:\MinGW\bin\
    !!!Do you still want to continue? Yes
```

I checked c:\MinGW\bin\ there is no such file

3) Qt Creator 2.6.0 for Windows (51 MB)also from [QT](http://qt-project.org/downloads) installed to C:\Qt\gtcreator-2.6.0 with default settings

4) Run the QT IDE

5) Open project or create new project. Another error occurs here

```
!!!No valid kits fond.
```

Qt Creator uses the invalid kit Desktop to parse the project.

6) Open Options->Build & Run->Kits (But I don't know how should I set Kits and where to find them).

7) Can you also help me, how to set Qt version
    (Options->Buid&Run->Qt Version)? Where do I find qmake.exe?

I also didn't find how to create GUI Application. There is no such option in New File or Project...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

That is quite tricky ;)

Precompiled Qt (MinGW) is only win32 (not win64).

Precompiled Qt is compiled with MinGW-g++ 4.4 and won't work with other.

You have to download *this* one:
http://get.qt.nokia.com/misc/MinGW-gcc440_1.zip

//// Edit: With this version of MinGW, gdb *won't* work (it's not python-enabled). Although QtSDK is depracted (and you won't find it on qt-project.org), I highly recommend downloading this online installer and, during the selection of components mark only MinGW. It will come with folder named "pythongdb".

http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html
(You may need to register. It's free.)
////

Add "Compiler" by g++.exe

Add "Qt Version" by qmake.exe.

Add "Kit" with Compiler and Qt Version configured above. You can try to change debugger from CDB to GDB.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed mingw, did you select the C++ compiler? It is not selected by default but you need it. Re-run the wizard and select that.

The kit is not valid because the C++ compiler cannot be found: try to install it first. If you still cannot setup this read the manual: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html. It is very complete.

qmake.exe is in *qt_directory*/bin/qmake.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ (Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org i suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org))

It works for me.