# Can't get Qt Creator debug working on Windows 10

Tags: qt, gdb, qt4, qt-creator

I'm starting to work with Qt 4.8.4 on Windows 10, and I've been trying to use the debugger for two days, but I just can't get it to work.

First of all, I've downloaded MinGW 4.4, and that's the version I selected for Qt installation. I've also installed the Windows 10 debugger tools from SDK. Both x86 and x64 CDB debuggers were automatically recognized by Qt Studio, and I manually added the GDB executable that came with MinGW.

The problem is that I can't get any of those debuggers to work, even with the simplest code I can imagine, where I just increment an integer.

When using any of the CDB debuggers, I get the following message:

> The selected debugger may be inappropiate for the inferior. Examining
> symbols and settings breakpoints by file name and line number may
> fail. The inferior is in the Portable Executable format. Selecting GDB
> as debugger would improve the debugging experience for this binary
> format

So I decide to select the GDB debugger I linked previously, and I get an error with message:

> No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command.

I have looked at this, but I don't know how to set up Qt Creator to use that file command.

I have no clue on how to solve this, and neither have I find any solution on the net. Reinstalling Qt didn't work either.

Can somebody help me please? I need this for my work and I'm completely stuck.

PS: Here are my kit and debuggers configuration in case they are helpful.
[image]
[image]
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure what version of Creator you're using, but the 2nd and 3rd replies in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245685/gdb-no-symbol-table-is-loaded might help. You *shouldn't* have to do this, but who knows...

Comment: @mzimmers I'm using Creator 4.13.2, and I've tried both solutions you posted, but neither -g nor -ggdb fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so it seems that it's not possible to use the debugger on this version of Qt with 64 bits Windows: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849872/qt-creator-4-8-4-windows-7-64bit-installation)